# How to get values of key value pairs in php object?

Tags: php

I have the ff:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [contest_id] => 520
    [type] => terms
    [name] => Terms and conditions
    [lang] => en_US
    [slug] => asdf
    [anchor_text] => 
    [title] => asdf
    [body] => 

    asdfasdfasdfasdf



    asdfasfasfsad



    asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf



    [created] => 2013-05-22 18:40:30
    [modified] => 2013-05-22 18:40:30
    [Media] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I want to get each of the values and output them in a page via html.

How do I get the ff?

```
<h1> Object[name] </h1>

<p> Object[body]</p>
and so on and so on...
```

Answer (score 1):

use this "->" to access object

```
<h1> $objectName->name </h1>

<p> $objectName->body</p>
```

and so on and so on...

Comment: Ah, I see that you understood the question better than I. This is the correct way.